# I want to change names Folders

Tags: windows

i have Folders I want something to change the Folders names

```
nameFolders
nameFolders
nameFolders
nameFolders
```

i want to change the names of Folders to the serial numbers

```
1nameFolders
2nameFolders
3nameFolders
4nameFolders
```

Comment: you mean like the `mv` command?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow, please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

There is no explicit command for renaming files, however `mv` can be used to acomplish same goal, you could write `mv file1 file1_renamed` and rename *file1* into *file1_renamed*.

Comment: i have windows bro :(

Comment: Why `linux` tag then? oO